Failure of sending emails using SMTP in cPanel with Laravel 11
Latest error I get is
Authenticator "LOGIN" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535 Incorrect authentication data".".
Authenticator "PLAIN" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535 Incorrect authentication data"."

I am using MS365 email account with an App password.
Started with:
'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'url' => null,
            'host' => 'smtp.office365.com',
            'port' => 587,
            'encryption' => 'tls',
            'username' => 'no-reply@mydomain.com',
            'password' => 'mypass',
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => null,
        ],

Got this error:
Unable to connect with STARTTLS: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed  


Then changed encryption to null & added 'verify_peer' => false:
'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'url' => null,
            'host' => 'smtp.office365.com',
            'port' => 587,
            'encryption' => null,
            'username' => 'no-reply@mydomain.com',
            'password' => 'mypass',
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => null,
            'verify_peer' => false,
        ],

Got this error:
Authenticator "LOGIN" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535 Incorrect authentication data".".
Authenticator "PLAIN" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535 Incorrect authentication data"."

WHM setting:

